# Why is the spinner not spinning/rotating?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have created a anchor link button where I want to show **Spinner animation** when I click on button in `:focus` state. I'm using **Font Awesome** to show animation but when I click on the button, the spinner animation is not working.

[image]

> **Note:** I don't want to use JavaScript here just want to do with **Pure
>   CSS**

Here is the CodePen link https://codepen.io/rhulkashyap/pen/vLPNdQ

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web);
 body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#button {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#button:before {
  content: "\f090";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#button:focus {
  background-color: #02b402;
}
#button:focus:before {
  content: "\f1ce";
  -webkit-animation: spin .8s ease infinite;
  animation: spin .8s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2> Click Here</h2>
<a id="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Enter In</a>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine (Chrome). What browser are you using and what do you mean by *not working*?

Comment: I am using Firefox Developer edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transforms are supposed to work only on block level elements (including `inline-block`). Making the pseudo-element as `display:inline-block` makes the animation work.

*After commenting on the question, I did see that the animation wasn't working in Chrome v50 (dev-m) also while it was working in Chrome v43. So, the current behavior seems to be consistent*

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web);
 body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#button {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#button:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f090";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
#button:focus {
  background-color: #02b402;
}
#button:focus:before {
  content: "\f1ce";
  -webkit-animation: spin .8s ease infinite;
  animation: spin .8s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2> Click Here</h2>
<a id="button" href="javascript:void(0)">Enter In</a>
```

Comment: @ketan: Sorry, I didn't get you. If you mean the presence of `transform` inside `@-webkit-keyframes` then it is required. There were older versions of Chrome which supported transforms without prefixes but not keyframes  (I think even upto v38 or something). The opposite is not required though.

Comment: On second thoughts, I think the unprefixed `transform` should not be required inside `@-webkit-keyframes` because WebKit should be able to take `-webkit-transform` when the unprexifed one is not there. But I still seem to remember running into this problem earlier. Anyway, for the latest versions just the standard versions will be more than enough :)